# Include in different file make different compiling error

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors

I'm have problem compiling a code.

ardutest.ino:

```cpp
#include "mylib.h"
#include <SD.h>

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  fn();
}
```

mylib.h:

```cpp
#ifndef mylib_h
#define mylib_h

#include "Arduino.h"


void fn(File &_file);

#endif
```

mylib.c:

```cpp
#include "mylib.h"

void fn(File &_file)
{
  _file = SD.open("LOG.TXT", FILE_WRITE);
  _file.println(42);
  _file.close();
}
```

When checking code in Arduino IDE I have this error:

```cpp
In file included from sketch/mylib.c:1:0:
mylib.h:7: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 void fn(File &_file);
          ^
mylib.c:3: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 void fn(File &_file)
          ^
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"
 Used: /home/mario/Arduino/libraries/SD
 Not used: /home/mario/Programs/arduino/libraries/SD
exit status 1
expected ')' before '&' token
```

But if I put SD.h in mylib.h (other files are the same):

```cpp
#ifndef mylib_h
#define mylib_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SD.h>

void fn(File &_file);

#endif
```

I have this error:

```cpp
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:26:0,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:29,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:423:14: error: unknown type name 'pin_map_t'
 static const pin_map_t digitalPinMap[] = {

              ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:447:69: error: 'pin_map_t' undeclared here (not in a function)
 static const uint8_t digitalPinCount = sizeof(digitalPinMap)/sizeof(pin_map_t);

                                                                     ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h: In function 'getPinMode':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:455:32: error: request for member 'ddr' in something not a structure or union
     return (*digitalPinMap[pin].ddr >> digitalPinMap[pin].bit) & 1;

                                ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:455:58: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
     return (*digitalPinMap[pin].ddr >> digitalPinMap[pin].bit) & 1;

                                                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h: In function 'setPinMode':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:464:26: error: request for member 'ddr' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].ddr |= 1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit;

                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:464:57: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].ddr |= 1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit;

                                                         ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:466:26: error: request for member 'ddr' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].ddr &= ~(1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit);

                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:466:59: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].ddr &= ~(1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit);

                                                           ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h: In function 'fastDigitalRead':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:475:32: error: request for member 'pin' in something not a structure or union
     return (*digitalPinMap[pin].pin >> digitalPinMap[pin].bit) & 1;

                                ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:475:58: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
     return (*digitalPinMap[pin].pin >> digitalPinMap[pin].bit) & 1;

                                                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h: In function 'fastDigitalWrite':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:484:26: error: request for member 'port' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].port |= 1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit;

                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:484:58: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].port |= 1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit;

                                                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:486:26: error: request for member 'port' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].port &= ~(1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit);

                          ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2PinMap.h:486:60: error: request for member 'bit' in something not a structure or union
       *digitalPinMap[pin].port &= ~(1 << digitalPinMap[pin].bit);

                                                            ^
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:29:0,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
Multiple libraries were found for "SD.h"
 Used: /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD
 Not used: /home/user/Programs/arduino/libraries/SD
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h: At top level:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:70:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const  SD_CHIP_SELECT_PIN = SS;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:79:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const  SPI_MOSI_PIN = MOSI;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:81:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const  SPI_MISO_PIN = MISO;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:83:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const  SPI_SCK_PIN = SCK;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:176:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Sd2Card {

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/Sd2Card.h:176:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 class Sd2Card {

               ^
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:30:0,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/FatStructs.h:405:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const DIR_ATT_FILE_TYPE_MASK = (DIR_ATT_VOLUME_ID | DIR_ATT_DIRECTORY);

 ^
In file included from /home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Print.h:27:0,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:31,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Printable.h:25:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Print;
 ^
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Printable.h:33:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Printable
 ^
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Printable.h:34:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:31:0,
                 from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Print.h:37:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Print
 ^
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/cores/arduino/Print.h:38:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:20:0,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:39:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class SdVolume;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:55:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const O_RDONLY = O_READ;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:59:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const O_WRONLY = O_WRITE;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:61:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const O_RDWR = (O_READ | O_WRITE);

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:63:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const O_ACCMODE = (O_READ | O_WRITE);

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:94:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 uint8_t const FAT_FILE_TYPE_MIN_DIR = FAT_FILE_TYPE_ROOT16;

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:137:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class SdFile : public Print {

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:137:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
 class SdFile : public Print {

              ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:431:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class SdVolume {

 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFat.h:431:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 class SdVolume {

                ^
In file included from /home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:21:0,
                 from sketch/mylib.h:5,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h: In function 'FreeRam':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:43:7: error: 'reinterpret_cast' undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {

       ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:43:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:43:24: error: expected expression before 'int'
   if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {

                        ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:45:36: error: expected expression before 'int'
     free_memory = reinterpret_cast<int>(&free_memory)

                                    ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:49:36: error: expected expression before 'int'
     free_memory = reinterpret_cast<int>(&free_memory)

                                    ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h: In function 'SerialPrint_P':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:62:52: error: 'Serial' undeclared (first use in this function)
   for (uint8_t c; (c = pgm_read_byte(str)); str++) Serial.write(c);

                                                    ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h: In function 'SerialPrintln_P':
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:72:3: error: 'Serial' undeclared (first use in this function)
   Serial.println();

   ^
In file included from sketch/mylib.h:5:0,
                 from sketch/mylib.c:1:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h: At top level:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:26:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace SDLib {
 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:26:17: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 namespace SDLib {
                 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:119:1: error: unknown type name 'using'
 using namespace SDLib;
 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:119:17: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SDLib'
 using namespace SDLib;
                 ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:123:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
 typedef SDLib::File    SDFile;
              ^
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/SD/src/SD.h:124:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
 typedef SDLib::SDClass SDFileSystemClass;
              ^
In file included from sketch/mylib.c:1:0:
mylib.h:7: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 void fn(File &_file);
              ^
mylib.c:3: error: expected ')' before '&' token
 void fn(File &_file)
              ^
exit status 1
expected ')' before '&' token
```

If I use SD.h function in mylib, I need this in mylib.h file. Why is it happens?

The first error is about passing object as function argument. I'm following sample I found in others forum, then I don't know why it isn't working.

[SOLVED]
I rename mylib.c to mylib.cpp and solved the problem.

Comment: in first case you have SD.h included after mylib.h so File is not known

Answer (score 1):

SD.h defines `class File`. Without that definition, 'File' is taken to be the name of an untyped argument (which will be assumed to be an int). Given that assumption, '&_file' is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are different strategies for organizing header file structure. I don't know which one you follow. Within the popular approach that strives to keep all header files in self-sufficient state, `mylib.h` should include `<SD.h>` since `mylib.h` uses `File` type.

Secondly, when you actually included `<SD.h>` into `mylib.h`, you ran into a different problem. SD library is written as a C++ library. Its header files will not compile as C code. Meanwhile, you are trying to compile `<SD.h>` in C mode by indirectly including it into a `mylib.c` file, which is what causes the errors.

---

This library's header files contain many bizarre coding patterns that might create an impression *as if* someone was trying to make these headers compatible with C code (`static const`? `static inline`? Etc.), but this is an illusion. The code is exclusively C++, not C.